# Knockout JS: Removing selected values from other, identical dropdowns

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, knockout.js

I'm working on a question/answer model, and I have multiple dropdowns that contain the same data (a bank of answers, if you will). The business logic here is that once someone selects an answer to a question, that answer can only be used once and isn't available for the other questions.

As such, I've found a way to bind all of my dropdowns to a single observableArray containing my answers, so that the dropdowns all contain the same options. What I would like to do is subscribe to the current value of one dropdown (out of many) and remove the selected value from all of the other dropdowns associated with them. Using Knockout, I've been able to subscribe a callback function to the changing values in my view.

In my callback function, I've found that removing the answer from my observableArray using the `remove` method of observableArray works, but it unfortunately removes the currently selected answer from all of the dropdowns - including the selected one! I've tried putting it back with a push command, but that causes problems as well. I can't seem to isolate the updates the way I want to.

Has anyone implemented something like this using Knockout before? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are bound to an array of options if you remove an item from it then correctly the options binding will reflect this. You can create independent virtual lists using computeds for each select box to bind to.

```
var viewModel = function(data) {
   var self = this;
   this.values = ko.observableArray([ "option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]);
   this.selected = [
       new ko.observable(),
       new ko.observable(),
       new ko.observable()
   ]

   this.remaining = function (current) {
       var selected = ko.toJS(self.selected),
           currentValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(current);
       var result = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.values(), function (option) {
           return option == currentValue || selected.indexOf(option) === -1;
       });
       return result;            
   };

   this.values1 = ko.computed(function () {
      return self.remaining(self.selected[0]);
   });
   this.values2 = ko.computed(function () {
      return self.remaining(self.selected[1]);
   });
   this.values3 = ko.computed(function () {
      return self.remaining(self.selected[2]);
   });
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/6uWEu/2/

**EDIT**

Here's how the above works. You need to bind each select to it's own observable so that as you select a value in the first the others can be updated. If you were to simply bind to the same list and remove from it each time a value was selected you would also be removing the value you had just selected, KO would update the select elements accordingly, it would be completely broken.

The above code solves this by filtering each in turn. I redirected each drop down to its own computed observable. These computed observables simply call a filter function that loops over the values array and filter out any that have been select that are **NOT** the currently selected value.

So if we start with all unselected the first select gets "option 1" selected the values1, values2 & values3 computed will be automatically recalculated by KO. Taking values1 as an example it will call

```
self.remaining("option 1");
```

values2 * values3 will also call remaining but with undefined, since they haven't been selected.

```
self.remaining(null);
```

The values array is filtered to options that haven't been selected and are not the current value. So the first call to remaining would result in `[ "option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]`. The second and third calls to remaining would result in `[ "option 2", "option 3"]`.

If you deselect the first select the same operations are performed with all options being returned.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks quite promising! Thank you for your reply. I'm going to have to massage it a lot to make it fit into my framework, but I think that this is a good starting point. Thank you!

Comment: @lunchmeat317 - Yeh it's not probably gunna fit perfectly but you get the idea. You'll need a separate filter set for each dropdown, how you do the remaining calculation is up to you. I just put them in the array so i could be lazy and do indexOf.

Comment: I hate to ask, but I've been hacking away at this code to try to get it to work within the framework I'm working with. Would you mind explaining your code a little bit - namely, the this.remaining function and how the observables work in this.selected?

Comment: Wow, thank you for the edit! I didn't realize that the observables were bound to the selects, which confused me a bit. I think that I understand exactly what you did now, though, which is awesome! Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on how you look at it), this requirement has been stripped from my project, so my dropdowns no longer have to do this. I will keep this in mind, though; I've learned something valuable that I can definitely find a use for. Marking as correct, and upvoting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do a similar thing, I had an `IsSet` property on the item, and two computed observables, one for the values where it is set and one where it is not set:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    this.self = this;
    self.originalList = ko.observableArray(data.list);
    self.selectedItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(function(item) { return item.IsSet(); });
    });
    self.unselectedItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(function(item) { return !item.IsSet(); });
    });
};
```

Comment: This looks like it might work for one Select container, but does it work for multiple?

Comment: Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with what you have so far?  I don't think I understand what you're trying to do.  You could have a computed for each drop-down and use an integer value instead of  a boolean value.

Comment: I apologize. I was trying to come up with something similar to the answer that @madcapnmckay provided - see his fiddle. I would have provided a JSFiddle, but the framework I'm using is somewhat extensive and would have required a rewrite of the code. (The guy who wrote the framework knows a lot more than I do.) I appreciate your answer, though, and I'm sure it'll come in handy.